# Multiple checkboxes in an AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, services, javascript

I've been developing this phonegap app and I'm stuck with a few things and one of them is multiple checkboxes - I hope you can help.

I've got the below code

*HTML*

```
<input type="date" id="date" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidden">
<fieldset id="oyuncuKategori">
    <legend>Kategori</legend>
    <div class="roundedOne">
        <input type="checkbox" id="oyuncu" name="kategori" value="oyuncu" class="squareTwo" />
        <label for="oyuncu">Oyuncu</label>
    </div>
    <div class="roundedOne">
        <input type="checkbox" id="yardimci_oyuncu" name="kategori" value="yardimci_oyuncu" class="squareTwo" />
        <label for="yardimci_oyuncu">Yardımcı oyuncu</label>
    </div>
    <div class="roundedOne">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cocuk_oyuncu" name="kategori" value="cocuk_oyuncu" class="squareTwo" />
        <label for="cocuk_oyuncu">Çocuk oyuncu</label>
    </div>
    <div class="roundedOne">
        <input type="checkbox" id="stand_hostesi" name="kategori" value="stand_hostesi" class="squareTwo" />
        <label for="stand_hostesi">Stand hostesi</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$("input[type='date']").on("change", function () {
    // var checkbox = $("#oyuncuKategori").serialize();
    var checkboxes = '';
    $('input[name=kategori]:checked').each(function(i, e) {
        checkboxes += '&node[field_kategorisi][und][value]='+$(this).val();
    });
    console.log(checkboxes);
    monthNames = [
        "Oca", "Şub", "Mar",
        "Nis", "May", "Haz", "Tem",
        "Ağu", "Eyl", "Eki",
        "Kas", "Ara"];
    date = new Date($("input").val());
    day = date.getDate();
    monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    year = date.getFullYear();
    finalDate = day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.rejicast.com/services/node.json',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'node[type]=oyuncu&node[title]=testnomikos456&node[language]=und'+ checkboxes +'&node[field_dogum_tarihi][und][0][value][date]=' + finalDate +',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, message) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
});
```

The thing is, this code works for creating a node but and inserts values for field_kategorisi overwriting other values, thus always the last checked box is there, while trying with `[und]['+i+'][value]` gives me `406: An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator`. and something like `Illegal choice Array in field_kategorisi` (I don't remember the English wording) on the server side. I'm really stumped. Can you give me any ideas?

UPDATE: When I make an ajax call, my POST looks like this.

> http://www.rejicast.com/services/node.json?node[type]=oyuncu&node[field_kategorisi][und][0][value]=stand_hostesi&node[field_kategorisi][und][1][value]=yesilcam

Comment: phonegap question in drupal? (though it is actually JS issue)

Comment: I asked here because the server is Drupal.

Comment: sorry; I understand that after re-read the error message and the intended values

Comment: hmm, also, come to think of it: how come you are sending data as as if it were `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but you set the `dataType` to `json`? Does `$.ajax` convert it automatically?

Comment: I have enabled both `json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for my endpoint. As for if `$.ajax` converts it automatically, I don't know.

Comment: @Kartagis have you tried submitting the data as JSON rather than form-encoded? In either case, if you could show just the final transmitted data in a separate code block, preferably without line wrapping, that would help. As it is, in order to understand what's happening, I have to parse your checkbox structure, and then the function that assembles this, and then concatenation in the data argument.

Comment: hi, in HTML first you have to change name="kategori" => name="kategori[]" - that means that you allow multiple checkboxes. Than on change get that form element.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Just looked at the code more closely, and saw this was the Services module.

From https://www.drupal.org/node/1971484#comment-7318114:

> For those of you who will probably have the same problem, here is the correct way to handle LIST type fields (in ex. below field_mosaic_bu):

```js
{
  "type":"TEST",
  "title":"TITLE",
  "uid":"1",
  "field_mosaic_bu":{ "und": ["bu name"] },
  "field_mosaic_var1":{ "und": [{ "value":"test1" }] },
  "field_mosaic_var2":{ "und": [{ "value":"test2" }] },
  "field_mosaic_var3":{ "und": [{ "value":"test3" }] },
  "field_mosaic_image":{ "und": [{ "fid":"4" }] }  
}
```

> Hope this helps someone. Took me a lot of time to figure this out.

---

When you get that message from Drupal, it generally means that you have tried to set a form value to a non-allowed value from the perspective of the field configuration. So, for example, `field_kategorisi` might be a Term Reference field. If you try to set it to a `tid` that isn't allowed according to the Drupal field configuration, that happens.

If it's a simple checkbox field, then adding the value you want to set to the Allowed Values in the field configuration should solve the issue.

If this doesn't help, please provide more information about the Drupal-side field configuration and whether you are using the form Drupal generates or not. It embeds various things like the form ID, form build ID, and so on into its form markup, so if problems persist, it could be related to it not receiving something it's expecting.

Comment: All the checkboxes' values are in the allowed values list. It even works if I omit ['+i+'], but overwriting all previous values.

Please see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11918318/Screenshot%20from%202015-10-17%2011%3A50%3A53.png

Comment: Updated my answer when I saw this was talking to the Services module. Hope that helps. You can try searching the issue queue further searching for "illegal choice" if not: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/services?text=illegal+choice&status=All

Comment: Yea, that approach works for select fields, but not for checkboxes; because if I omit [0] it works, but also overwrites the value from the previous checkbox.

Comment: Can you add the actual POST JSON you are sending to the endpoint to your question? Should be able to find this in the Network tab. Generally, checkboxes expressed in PHP code are like this: `array(
      'value1' => TRUE,
      'value3' => TRUE,)`

Empty values are not set or set to `0`/`FALSE`